# How to style HTML select/option tag?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, styles

I would like to create a dropdown menu with html select thus I would like to style it as well. I would like to set a padding to the option tags so they wouldn't be so overcrowded, but I can't do so. (it doesn't work)
any idea?

```
#categories
{
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: #826B78;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border: none;
outline: none;
}

#categories option
{
margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

the categories id belongs to the select tag

Comment: This will be closed soon as "not a real question". *It doesn't work* means NOTHING if you don't provide 1) The code you tried, and 2) what exactly is not working

Comment: This question is asked so often, did you search for your answer? Check the **related questions >**

Comment: i provided the code, whats not working is the padding and the font size

Comment: It totally works: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg7qa/ downvote is near...

Comment: yeah, actually, it doesn't work at all. do you see any padding on the options???????

Comment: With over ten thousand views, there is no single upvote?

Comment: I came across this question almost 3 years after the original post.  I thought it was pretty good and it helped me solve my problem.  Sorry people were flaming you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to style select menu with css. The Best way of doing it is with jquery u can style and have a better control over the code with jquery. Just use a custom jquery like http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

I have just made an example of styling select with jquery, you can check the demo here

```js
// Code to convert select to UL
$('.select').each(function() {
  var $select = $(this).find('select'),
    $list = $('<ul />');
  $select.find('option').each(function() {
    $list.append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
  });
  //Remove the select after the values are taken
  $select.after($list).remove();


  //Append Default text to show the selected
  $(this).append('<span>select</span>')
  var firsttxt = $(this).find('li:first-child').text();
  $(this).find('span').text(firsttxt)

  // On click show the UL
  $(this).on('click', 'span', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show();
  });

  // On select of list select the item
  $(this).on('click', 'li', function() {
    var gettext = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.select').find('span').text(gettext);
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
  });

})


// On click out hide the UL
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('.select ul').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial', san-serif;
}

.select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.select span {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.select ul {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.select ul > li {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.select ul > li {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.select ul > li:hover {
  background: #e4f4fa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>First Select</label>
<div class="select">  
    <select>
         <option>Item</option>
         <option>Item 2</option>
         <option>Item 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<label>Second Select</label>
<div class="select">
    <select>
         <option>this 1</option>
         <option>this 2</option>
         <option>this 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i am not allowed to use jquery, isnt it possible with javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the default setting can enable you a little more freedom - give your select a class, within that class use the following:

```
-webkit-appearance:none; 
-moz-appearance:none; 
 appearance:none;
```

and then add in your default style

Answer (score 1):

html5 specification does not provide generic style properties to customize this user input control element. the only way found on net was using label element to reference this control for styling purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can give style to select tag like this or you can use class name or id as well

```
select
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #555555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> Avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.

According to those [bootstrap people](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

Comment: Note that comment that you're quoting [seems to be specifically](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) for using the `select` tag with Bootstrap's `.inputGroup` class.