# How to style select tags on a Mac

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, coding-style

Does anyone know how to style "select" tags for mac. chrome safari etc?

I know you can strip the  user style agent by adding -webkit-appearance: none; but this gets rid of the arrow too.

Are there any other ways or is this the only one?

here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/S4TfZ/1/

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 no-padding-left">
            <select class="form-control form-location indent-left full-width">
                <option>Select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 no-padding-left">
            <select class="form-control form-location indent-left full-width">
                <option>Select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 no-padding-left">
            <select class="form-control form-location indent-left full-width">
                <option>Select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 push-right no-padding-right ">
            <div class="arrow-box">
                <p>Sell yourself and say what makes you, you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try using some jQuery plugin that does this, but then it'd be applied to the `select` in all browsers, not only those in OS X.

Comment: I agree with @Zentaurus, there are probably ways to do this, but the results will be much cleaner and look more alike across browsers by using JS/jQuery.

Comment: Ok, thanks , my jquery isnnt very strong. so you have any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Styling `<select>` menu with CSS is very difficult. If I ever needed styling it, I would use jQuery. With jQuery you can control the code and how it acts much better than only CSS. I suggest you to read this very helpful articles: 
**[How to style HTML select/option tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186866/how-to-style-html-select-option-tag)**
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ 
http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/